# Adding 2 numbers in NSMutableArray

Tags: ios, nsmutablearray, sum

Well, sad to say, but I have 2 questions, which I wish I could've answered myself:

a)  If I have an NSMutableArray of say 5 elements and want to add objects 0 and 1 together, how would I do it?

e.g.

```
NSMutableArray *a =[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:3,7,2, 1,6, nil];
NSMutableArray *c = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:a copyItems:YES];

[c replaceObjectAtIndex:1 withObject:
            ([[c objectAtIndex:0] intValue]+ 
             [[c objectAtIndex:1] intValue])];
```

b) This is the embarrassing part:  how would I create a simple program in Xcode to test this, and try various other iterations?  Is there some pre-made skeleton that has all the stuff you need just to plop down these 3 lines of code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`NSMutableArray` only accepts object, not primitive. So whatever you're trying to do now, won't work.

```
NSMutableArray *a =[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:[NSNumber numberWithInt:3], [NSNumber numberWithInt:7], nil]; // and so on

[c replaceObjectAtIndex:1 withObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:
        ([[c objectAtIndex:0] intValue]+ 
         [[c objectAtIndex:1] intValue])]];
```

2) Just create a new project, copy & paste your code in one of the files that is created by XCode for you, (main.m perhaps)

Comment: Thank you for the insightful, albeit complicated, way to add 2 numbers.  It was especially confusing after I tried other weird things such as NSUInteger, and I even made a mistake in the declaration of the array *a.    Peter      PS: I still have to try your suggestion on creating a new project, but I wanted to answer quickly while my initial question was answered.

Answer (score 0):

1. An int is NOT an object.
2. Have you opened Xcode before? Try File > new.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by #1 (is it some implied criticism?).  I like the answer of #2 from the person who answered above, and which I accepted.  As to #3,  I did the File > new, and created a project called Skeleton, but it got more and more complex, so I abandoned it without trying the sample code.